# I can't write text in a category in Json

Tags: python, json

I'm new to JSON. I'm trying to write to the "x" category in the Json file using Python, but the posts I write go to the bottom of the Json file. I am trying to store data.

```
    x = open("x.json", "a", encoding="utf-8")
    x_r.write(
        ',\n{'
        '"id":'
        f'"{id}"'
        ', "name":'
        f'"{name}"'
        "}"
    )
```

must be:

```
{
  "x": [
    {"id": "x", "name": "x"},
    {"id": "x", "name": "x"}

  ]
}
```

at the moment:

```
{
  "servers": [

  ]
}
{"id": "x", "name": "x"},
{"id": "x", "name": "x"}
```

Comment: Don’t try to modify and write to json like text. Use the `json` package.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The approach of the code is fundamentally wrong. Please use the `json` standard library module to parse the file, use your own code to change the **data structure** that the file represents, and then use `json` again to write the modified file. Files **do not have an "insert mode"**, and JSON is not designed to be modified in that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't read/write JSON files directly. Instead, use the JSON parser from the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html) standard library module:

```py
import json

with open("your_json_file.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

data["servers"] = [{"id": "x", "name": "x"}, {"id": "x", "name": "x"}]

with open("output_file.json", "w") as f_out:
    json.dump(data, f_out, indent=4)
```

---

If the content of `your_json_file.json` was:

```json
{
  "servers": [

  ]
}
```

then `output_file.json` will be:

```json
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "id": "x",
            "name": "x"
        },
        {
            "id": "x",
            "name": "x"
        }
    ]
}
```